# Custom Name Entity Regognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have the following sentence:

```
text="The weather is extremely severe in England"
```

I want to perform a custom `Name Entity Recognition (NER)` procedure

First a normal `NER` procedure will output `England` with a `GPE` label

```
pip install spacy

!python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg

import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

doc = nlp(text)

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text+' - '+ent.label_+' - '+str(spacy.explain(ent.label_)))

Result: England - GPE - Countries, cities, states
```

However, I want the whole sentence to take the tag `High-Severity`.

So I am doing the following procedure:

```
from spacy.strings import StringStore

new_hash = StringStore([u'High_Severity']) # <-- match id
nlp.vocab.strings.add('High_Severity')

from spacy.tokens import Span

# Get the hash value of the ORG entity label
High_Severity = doc.vocab.strings[u'High_Severity']  

# Create a Span for the new entity
new_ent = Span(doc, 0, 7, label=High_Severity)

# Add the entity to the existing Doc object
doc.ents = list(doc.ents) + [new_ent]
```

I am taking the following error:

```
ValueError: [E1010] Unable to set entity information for token 6 which is included in more than one span in entities, blocked, missing or outside.
```

From my understanding, this is happening because `NER` has already recognised `England` as `GRE` and cannot add a label over the existing label.

I tried to execute the custom `NER` code (i.e, without first running the normal `NER` code) but this did not solve my problem.

Any ideas on how to Solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that what you need is NER ?
From what I am seeing, you're trying to assign a label to a group of contiguous spans with some overlapping entities.
Why don't you take a look at The spanCategorizer and the spanRuler first ?

https://spacy.io/api/spancategorizer  and
https://spacy.io/api/spanruler

Comment: If you want to label the whole sentence it sounds like this is a text categorization problem.

Comment: @Hannibal I don't understand why you assume that those are "a group of continuous spans". I would say it is a single span (continuous tokens). But correct me if I am wrong. I understand the example of xavi as a simple one, I.e. the real text might have multiple of those long spans to be implemented as NER probably to be able to use other functionality of spacy.

Comment: @JFerro Thanks for correcting me, I meant to say group of continuous tokens. That's why I recommended the spancat and spanruler :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it looks like NER do not allow overlapping, and that is your problem, your second part of the code tries to create a ner containing another ner, hence, it fails.
see in:

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/10885

and therefore spacy has spans categorization.

I did not find yet the way to characterized a predefined span (not coming from a trained model)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the new hash in the string store? Due to the underscore? Thx

Comment: I am also trying out this code of yours. Actually you are right, I am very surprised by the fact that entitities can not have overlapping apparently.

Comment: Actually if you disable NER pipe it would work:
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable = ['ner'])

Comment: If you have a text like "I the team I like the most is celtics of boston" I understand that I can not create a NER "baskeball_team" for "celtics of boston" because "boston" is already an entity.

Comment: thank you very much. Actually, as you mentioned nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable = ['ner']) this works fine